# Function to search of multiple patterns using grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to make a bash script to use grep to search for lines which have multiple patterns (case-insensitive). I want to create a bash script which I can use as follows:

```
myscript file.txt pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
```

and it should get traslated to:

```
grep -i --color=always pattern1 file.txt | grep -i pattern2 | grep -i pattern3
```

I tried following bash script, but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -i --color=always $2 $1 | grep -i $3 | grep -i $4 | grep -i $5 | grep -i $6 | grep -i $7
```

The error is:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: But what's the goal of this?

Comment: Do you wan't *undefined* number of pattern?

Comment: Yes. The bash script should be able to run with first filename argument and then variable number of pattern arguments (should be able to handle at least 6 patterns- ideally any number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do a recursive function:

```
search() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
        local pat=$1
        shift
        grep "$pat" | search "$@"
    else
         cat
    fi
}
```

In your script you would call this function and pass the search patterns as arguments. Say that `$1` is the file and the rest of the arguments are patterns then you would do

```
file=$1
shift
cat "$file" | search "$@"
```

Comment: How will the search function be used in bash script.

Comment: Can there be an error message if none or only 1 argument is entered?

Answer (score 1):

When you have GNU awk, you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} /pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && /pattern3/' file.txt
```

EDIT:
You can use this in a script like this:

```
inputfile="$1"
shift
awk -f <(echo "BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}"; printf " /%s/ &&" $* | sed 's/&&$//') "${inputfile}"
```

Comment: "awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} /$2/ && /$3/ && /$4/' $1" does not work in a bash script. Also what if only 2 patterns are sent? I want it to handle a variable number of patterns that may be sent.

Comment: I edited the answer to show haw to handle this in a script with a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score -1):

If you omit one argument or other at the end, so that $3 etc. will be missing, then some grep command will not receive an argument and will whine.